# How much control do we have over CPT rewrite slugs? Can I create a "root" page for my CPT with out the page path, and then have paths for other pages?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, rewrite-rules, paths

Say I have a CPT called I dunno, `"Library"` which is just a set of "pages" (`"has_archive" => false`) and the rewrite slug is "library".  I also intend to have a set of pages like "about", "archive", and "new books".

Can I do something so that I make a page called "home" and instead of its url being `https://example.org/library/home` could it be `https://example.org/library`? And then the about page would have the url of `https://example.com/library/about`

NOTE - I know that I *could* set the rewrite slug to "/" and then create a new page named "library" and then make things like the "about" or "archive" pages children of "library" but I feel like is just an extra step my users are going to be unhappy about having to do.

And if I made a second CPT, "library-books" would there be away to set its rewrite slug to `"library/books"` or would I need a totally different path?  so I would want `https://example.org/library/books` to be the archive for the "library-books" CPT and then `https://example.org/library/books/book-title` for the individual book posts.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, you could do:

```php
// Via the init hook, do all these:

register_post_type( 'library-books', [
    'public'      => true,
    'label'       => 'Library Books',
    'rewrite'     => [ 'with_front' => false, 'slug' => 'library/books' ],
    'has_archive' => 'library/books',
    // other args here
] );

register_post_type( 'library', [
    'public'      => true,
    'label'       => 'Libraries',
    'rewrite'     => [ 'with_front' => false, 'slug' => 'library' ],
    'has_archive' => false,
    // other args here
] );

add_rewrite_rule( '^library/?$', 'index.php?library=home', 'top' );
```

I.e.

- Register the `library-books` CPT first, with `library/books` as the rewrite slug as well as `has_archive`.
- Then register the `library` CPT with `library` as the rewrite slug, and `has_archive` set to `false`.
- And register a custom rewrite rule for the `example.com/library` which (internally) loads `example.com/library/home` (which is a post of the `library` CPT, although you can really modify the rewrite rule's query to load a post of a different post type such as `page`).

But of course, in your `library` CPT, you shouldn't have a post with `books` as the slug.